# How can I add my custom method for image preprocessing task in model.Sequential() of Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I have implemented a code to perform image preprocessing tasks. And it is a fully functioning method but it works with one image at a time. But I don't know how to make the function compatible with the tf dataset as I used OpenCV to perform the image processing task. And, how can I add this layer to `models.Sequential()` to match with the `Sequential()` requirements type?
The code where I want to add my custom function is -

```
model = models.Sequential([
    resize_and_rescale,
    data_augmentation,
    custom_function_want_to_add_here(),
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3,),activation = 'relu', input_shape = input_shape),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3,),activation = 'relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'),
    layers.Dense(n_classes,activation='softmax'),
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

1. put your custom function to a [custom TensorFlow layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers)

   - the convenience of this method is that all the logic is kept inside the model, however, implementation could be challenging since it would require the layer logic to work with TensorFlow backend
2. put the image preprocessing outside of the model

   - since the preprocessing does not need any training, you can put it outside the model (so that the first layer of the model would be `layers.Conv2D(32, ...)`)

Since your custom logic requires calling a function from the OpenCV library (if I understood correctly) I would probably recommend the second approach. It will be easier to make the function work with the `tf.data.Dataset` than it would be to make it work inside the model.

Comment: hi @druskacik, Thank you so much for your answer. Actually, I want to add the preprocessing layer to the model architecture. I think the first approach would solve the situation. In this case, I will do some processing tasks for getting the mask in an image then the processed image with having the same image size would then passing to the next layer. Normally, when we sent the image data can you tell me that does it goes after some modification or just as it is? thank you again

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand the question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thank you fortunately I have got the answer to my previous question. But, I'm facing a problem that is -
The actual error from `call` is: Exception encountered when calling layer 'mask_region_of_interest_2' (type MaskRegionOfInterest).

in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-19-44593f79b108>", line 10, in call  *
        img = cv2.imread(inputs, 1)

    TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename'


Call arguments received by layer 'mask_region_of_interest_2' (type MaskRegionOfInterest):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(32, 512, 512, 3), dtype=float32).